# Custom events in VB

Tags: vb.net, events

I have the following C# which I'm trying to convert to VB. I rarely use VB so am a bit stuck on this one. What is the proper way to raise custom events in VB for this example?

```
webControl.TitleChanged += OnTitleChanged;
webControl.AddressChanged += OnAddressChanged;

[...]

private void OnTitleChanged( object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e )
{
    this.Text = e.Title;
}

private void OnAddressChanged( object sender, UrlEventArgs e )
{
    this.Text = e.Url.ToString();
}
```

I've tried the following but can't see where I can access the `EventArgs`

```
AddHandler webControl.TitleChanged, AddressOf OnTitleChanged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your method that will handle the event as:

```
Private Sub OnTitleChanged(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as TitleChangedEventArgs)
```

Remember to use `Imports` to import the namespace for `TitleChangedEventArgs` or use full namespace when declaring the method.

Comment: Sorry I'm being a bit dim. I don't want to manually raise the event, I want the webControl to raise the event on it's own?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. So do you already have `OnTitleChanged` in VB?

Comment: Yes currently I have Private Sub OnTitleChanged()... but can't get the arguments `e` or `sender`

Comment: so do you have it declared as `Private Sub OnTitleChanged(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as TitleChangedEventArgs)`? If so, you don't need anything else...

Comment: Thanks it works. I hadn't used Imports with the correct .dll which was why it was giving an error. If you add an answer I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: Is `TitleChangedEventArgs` a private or protected class? Can't be. Maybe you need `Imports` for a proper namespace or use a full namespace when declaring your param.